# How to remove white space on table border

Tags: html, css

I have some spaces between my borders in a table. And I cant figure out why, but the margin doesn't work. since it's a table I have a left border on both td and th. but I also have a space between the side borders and top/bottom border.

```css
.table-bordered {
    border: 1px solid #9a9a9a !important;
}
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
    .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
    .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
    .table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
    .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
    .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
        border: 1px solid #9a9a9a !important;
        /* outline: none; */
    }
.table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
}
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td.border-bottom-white {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" >
  <thead>
  <tr >
    <td>H1</td>
     <td>H2</td>
      <td>H3</td>
      <td>H1</td>
     <td>H2</td>
      <td>H3</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
    <tr >
    <td colspan ="3" class="border-bottom-white" ></td>
    <td >2</td>
    <td >3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td colspan ="3" class="border-bottom-white" ></td>
    <td >2</td>
    <td >3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr >
    <td  colspan ="3"  ></td>
    <td >2</td>
    <td >3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to inspect the element using dev tools.

Comment: Tried to inspect... but not getting the fix

Comment: That white space is your `border-bottom`. The border runs edge to edge so it's overlapping your overall border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this:

```css
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #9a9a9a !important;
}

.table-bordered>thead>tr>th,
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th,
.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-bordered>thead>tr>td,
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,
.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #9a9a9a !important;
  /* outline: none; */
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td.border-bottom-white {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>H1</td>
      <td>H2</td>
      <td>H3</td>
      <td>H1</td>
      <td>H2</td>
      <td>H3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="border-bottom-white"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="border-bottom-white"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```